I Would like One Http call Completed before the next in angular
here is my Http requests
in getAllUserData() i would like this.getAnXSRfToken() to finish exe before proceeding with the http request;
  getAllUserData() {
    //get XSRF token
    this.getAnXSRfToken();
    return this.http
      .post<User[]>('http://localhost:8080/user/get-all-users-post', null, {
        observe: 'response',
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .subscribe({
        next: (array) => {
          this.allUsersData.next(array.body);
        },
        error: (e) => {
          console.log(e);
        },
      });
  }

here is the this.getAnXSRfToken() method
  getAnXSRfToken() {
    return this.http
      .post<{
        parameterName: string;
        headerName: string;
        token: string;
      }>('http://localhost:8080/user/getXSRfToken', null)
      .subscribe({
        next: (tokenData) => {
          console.log('REQ --- token ---generated ');
          console.log(tokenData.token);
          this.XSRF_TOKEN.next(tokenData.token);
        },
        error: (e) => console.log(e),
      });
  }


Remove the subscribes and just return the observable, then you can use switchMap to switch from the XHR API call, to the other API call sequentially!
getAllUserData() {
    //get XSRF token
    this.getAnXSRfToken().pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
            return this.http
                .post<User[]>('http://localhost:8080/user/get-all-users-post', null, {
                    observe: 'response',
                    withCredentials: true,
                }).pipe(//array parameter was missed out 
                    tap((array) => {
                        this.allUsersData.next(array.body);
                    })
                )
        })
    ).subscribe();

}

getAnXSRfToken() {
    return this.http
        .post<{
            parameterName: string;
            headerName: string;
            token: string;
        }>('http://localhost:8080/user/getXSRfToken', null)
        .pipe(
            tap((tokenData) => {
                console.log('REQ --- token ---generated ');
                console.log(tokenData.token);
                this.XSRF_TOKEN.next(tokenData.token);
            })
        );
}


Thanks again :) ... your solutions are always the best ...!
